# Do Silverlight development tools depend on .NET runtime?

Tags: .net, silverlight

If I never had a .NET installed on my machine - would I be able to develop a Silverlight application using only Silverlight development tools?

In other words - do the Silverlight development tools depend on .NET?

If yes - where do I find information on what version of .NET each of Silverlight version depends on?

Comment: Check here: http://www.microsoft.com/getsilverlight/Get-Started/Install/Default.aspx

Comment: these are requirements for the client running Silverlight application. My question is specifically about developing. Please read carefully. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Silverlight CLR` is standalone runtime, independent from `.NET CLR`. In other words, you can browse Silverlight application(run `Sl` bytecode on `SL CLR`) without `.NET`.
Theoretically, you can develop Silverlight .XAP assembly without `.NET`, but all the same you need to develop hosting application for it(simple `ASP.NET` project) that requires `.NET`.

Comment: `Seems` the `be` the new `trend` to format `every` modulo `N` word as `code`.

Comment: Sure! Code formatting should, in my opinion, be reserved for formatting code, not arbitrary keywords.

Comment: Dmitry is there a limitation on what .NET version should your ASP.NET host to be ran in order to work with a specific Silverlight version or it doesn't matter?